# centos firewall, split webtraffic based on subDomain name

Tags: centos, firewall

I have a CentOS 7 firewall and 1 public IP available (I maybe get a second) and 
we have 2 subdomains

1. crm.domain.com (its a appliance crm)
2. www.domain.com (there should be the company website)

How can I split the web traffic based on the subdomain name to which server it should route.

thx for any hints

Answer (score 0):

To split web traffic based on subdomains better to use something like `traefik` of `nginx`. The solution for nginx described in answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905378/nginx-subdomain-configuration.